# PayPal user identifier

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to find some hard identifier that don't change during PayPal account lifetime,

It seems like the REST API has its own user identifier (that can be returned from the *openidconnect/userinfo* resource when scope has *openid*)

Unfortunately, This ID is not what the Adaptive API expect when issuing a PayRequest:

> **sender.accountId**: Account ID value (which is the same as the Payer ID value used in the Express Checkout API). The account ID value is an encrypted PayPal account ID.

This is confusing, I understand the REST API is different than the Adaptive API and using email is not sufficient because we need to store the identifier on our database for long term and user may change his email address through PayPal,

Thanks,

Asaf.

Comment: What are you doing that you need to store Payer ID's?  If you need to make API calls on behalf of other users that's where the Permissions API, which as you said is token based, comes into play.

Comment: The only way I know that you can get the Payer ID is to have the user enter it manually or get it from GetExpressCheckoutDetails while in that Express Checkout flow.

Comment: I cannot request a token as it requires user intervention, with PayRequest I can process payments in the future without requiring any user interaction as the pre approval already approved, and PayRequest requires the senderId.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the sender ID when working with preapproved payments.  The preapproval key itself relates to the sender who approved it.

Here's a sample request and response for Pay using a preapproval key that works just fine without any sender ID.

**Request**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PayRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <requestEnvelope xmlns="">
    <detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel>
    <errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage>
  </requestEnvelope>
  <actionType xmlns="">PAY</actionType>
  <cancelUrl xmlns="">http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Cancel.php</cancelUrl>
  <clientDetails xmlns="">
    <applicationId xmlns="">APP-80W284485P519543T</applicationId>
    <ipAddress xmlns="">192.168.1.1</ipAddress>
  </clientDetails>
  <currencyCode xmlns="">USD</currencyCode>
  <preapprovalKey xmlns="">PA-2AY45015CC5060422</preapprovalKey>
  <receiverList xmlns="">
    <receiver xmlns="">
      <amount xmlns="">5.00</amount>
      <email xmlns="">usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com</email>
    </receiver>
  </receiverList>
  <sender>
    <useCredentials xmlns=""></useCredentials>
  </sender>
  <account xmlns="">
    <phone xmlns=""></phone>
  </account>
  <returnUrl xmlns="">http://paypal.angelleye.com/paypal/class/1.2/Pay_Return.php</returnUrl>
</PayRequest>
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<ns2:PayResponse xmlns:ns2="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap">
  <responseEnvelope>
    <timestamp>2013-09-24T13:57:52.350-07:00</timestamp>
    <ack>Success</ack>
    <correlationId>2fa4316b879b9</correlationId>
    <build>7767516</build>
  </responseEnvelope>
  <payKey>AP-5632737798659023M</payKey>
  <paymentExecStatus>COMPLETED</paymentExecStatus>
  <paymentInfoList>
    <paymentInfo>
      <transactionId>53664474R26308454</transactionId>
      <transactionStatus>COMPLETED</transactionStatus>
      <receiver>
        <amount>5.00</amount>
        <email>usb_1329725429_biz@angelleye.com</email>
        <primary>false</primary>
        <accountId>C9TAVNJFATXCS</accountId>
      </receiver>
      <pendingRefund>false</pendingRefund>
      <senderTransactionId>3CV49919EJ546411E</senderTransactionId>
      <senderTransactionStatus>COMPLETED</senderTransactionStatus>
    </paymentInfo>
  </paymentInfoList>
  <sender>
    <accountId>E7BTGVXBFSUAU</accountId>
  </sender>
</ns2:PayResponse>
```

You can see above the response actually includes the sender ID which it knows based on the preapproval key provided in the request.

Comment: I was talking about the 'receiver' tag not the sender, it should contain the email or accountId, i'd like to collect the accountId of the receiver AHEAD, but when user logs in, I can't get it as the rest api for getting user details only exposes the openID user ID, so I need some API resource or some other way to retrieve the ID of the retrieve ahead. thanks!